# Nothing is appearing in my TabbedPanel in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to code up a program using the TabbedPanel class. I am going to use ScreenManager and navbuttons to navigate different screens within each tab. Problem is nothing is showing up. At first at least the NavLayout was showing up but now all that appears are the tabs with their respective names. How do I get both Navigation buttons and Screen to show up in the tab.

```
ex1.kv


<MainPanel>:
    id: mp
    usb_tab_wid: usb_tab
    remote_tab_wid: remote_tab
    sd_tab_wid: sd_tab

    size_hint: 1,1
    tab_width: 65
    do_default_tab: False
    tab_pos: 'top_right'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        id: usb_tab
        text: 'Usb'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            UsbScreenManager:
            NavLayout:


    TabbedPanelItem:
        id: remote_tab
        text: 'Remote'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        id: sd_tab
        text: 'SD'





<NavLayout>:
    id: grid1
    spacing: 5,5

    rows: 1
    size_hint: 1, .2
    LeftButton:
        id: left_arrow_button

        Image:
            source: 'left_arrow_iconb.png'
            center: left_arrow_button.center
            size: grid1.width*.8, grid1.height*.8

    BackButton:
        id: back_button

        Image:
            source: 'back_iconb.png'
            center: back_button.center
            size: grid1.width*.8, grid1.height*.8
    RightButton:
        id: right_arrow_button

        Image:
            source: 'right_arrow_iconb.png'
            center: right_arrow_button.center
            size: grid1.width*.8, grid1.height*.8

usb.kv




<UsbScreenManager>:
    id: usb_screen_manager
    H2HScreen:
        name: 'h2h'
    V9validationScreen:
        name: 'v9'

<H2HScreen>:
    name: 'h2h'
    BoxLayout:
        TestIcon:
            source: 'h2h.png'

<V9validationScreen>:
    name: 'v9'
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: 'V9 tests'

ex1.py

import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')
import subprocess
import csv
from datetime import datetime
import usb.core
import usb.util
import threading
import time
from functools import partial

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.image import Image

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout






class MainPanel(TabbedPanel):
    usb_tab_wid = ObjectProperty()
    remote_tab_wid = ObjectProperty()
    sd_tab_wid = ObjectProperty()

    usbman = ObjectProperty(None)

    def switch_to(self, header):
        pass
    def print_wd(self):
        for widget in self.walk():
            print("[]->{}".format(widget, widget.id))

    def on_current_tab(self, b, c):
        print(self.current_tab)
        #return super(MainPanel, self).on_current_tab()


    #print(usb_tab_wid)
    pass

class TestIcon(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass




class UsbScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class H2HScreen(Screen):
    pass


class V9validationScreen(Screen):
    pass


class RemoteScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class SDcardScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass




class NavLayout(GridLayout):
    pass

class LeftButton(Button):
    sm = ObjectProperty()
    mp = MainPanel()


    ct= mp.current_tab


    #print (ct)

    pass

class RightButton(Button):
    sm = ObjectProperty()
    panel = ObjectProperty()
    pass

class BackButton(Button):
    sm = ObjectProperty()
    panel = ObjectProperty()

    def active_panel():
        #if current tab is __ then load corresponding screen manager 
        pass
    pass



class Sam1App(App):
    def build(self):

        return MainPanel()

Builder.load_file("usb.kv")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Sam1App().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found I overrode the switch_to method for TabbedPanel but did not define anything. So the TabbedPanel did not know what to switch to so it displayed nothing.